# Mono For Android Hello World code throws AndroidManifest.xml error

Tags: xamarin.android

I recently downloaded the trial version of Mono For Android. I tried running the Hello World tutorial. I receive the following error:

Tried to launch activity 'HelloMonoDroid.HelloMonoDroid/hellomonodroid.Activity1', but the device could not find it.

A common cause of this is manually adding an  to your AndroidManifest.xml whose name does not match your Activity class.

Consider using the [Activity] attribute instead:
http://monodroid.net/Tutorials/Working_with_AndroidManifest.xml

I triple checked my code and didn't see any differences between it and the posted code in the tutorial. So I tried to create a new Mono For Android Project and ran it without modification. I named the Project Driver. Here is the error I received:

Tried to launch activity 'Driver.Driver/driver.Activity1', but the device could not find it.

A common cause of this is manually adding an  to your AndroidManifest.xml whose name does not match your Activity class.

Consider using the [Activity] attribute instead:
http://monodroid.net/Tutorials/Working_with_AndroidManifest.xml

Notice it is the same as the original error with only the activity name changed. This is a simple solution. I am not creating a AndroidManifest.xml file manually. Is this a bug with the Mono For Android product?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools->Options->Mono for Android and turn on adb logging.

This should write a log to your desktop that might give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Aha, thanks I've found the issue. There is a place in that dialog (Tools->Options->Mono For Android) that sets the Android SDK path. After doing this the solution deploys and works with no trouble. I thought I told the installer where the SDK was, but apparently not. Its possible I got myself confused as I'm evaluating the Eclipse/Android SDK development environment in parrallel.